# Network request does not execute successfully while using runnable

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, runnable

I'm using `Retrofit2` and `RxJava2` for my network requests.

I've a simple runnable that includes:

```
override fun run() {
    handler.postDelayed(this, interval)
    DummyService.syncData(context, null)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe( response -> {
                    //nothing
                }, e -> {
                    //nothing
                });
}
```

And my `syncData` function looks like this:

```
fun syncData(): Single<Unit> {
    Log.d("...", "sync before")
    return service.test(null)
                .onErrorResumeNext(ErrorHandler(BaseErrorParser()))
                .map { jsonApiObject ->
                     Log.d("...", "sync WHOLE DATA")


                    ....
                }
}
```

In log I can see, that runnable works good - `syncData()` gets called and I see in logs `"sync before"` message, but I do not see `"sync WHOLE DATA"`. I did try to place a breakpoint - it shows check (as it was there, but debugger never stops [hits] that point really). I can see that network request is executed, but it does not succeed. Why is that? If I call the very same function normally (not from runnable), it works okay.

Comment: You are calling `syncData(context, null)` but you only define `syncData()` with no arguments. Where do you define the one with 2 arguments?

Answer (score 0):

your `syncData` function return `Single` object. you should execute it by

```
DummyService.syncData(context, null).subscribe(response -> {

})
```

Comment: Updated post. Still same problem. :/